How to reduce prediction error in a long-term time series prediction

In this project, I aim to predict a missing segment of 100,000 points in the middle of a sequence using a total of 100,000 points before and after the gap. I have already tried polynomial fitting and other methods, but the fitting results were poor. Therefore, I decided to try deep learning models for regression to fit the middle segment.
However, the signal curve seems to have only a general trend, without any periodic or seasonal characteristics. I tried using VAE, transformer, LSTM, and RNN models for fitting and prediction. Except for the transformer, all other models produced errors above 0.5, so I focused on optimizing the transformer model as much as possible.
I understand that this is a long-sequence prediction task. Although I am using a transformer model to predict the middle data, the fitting error still shows an S-curve shape. Now, I want to reduce this fitting error. Could you suggest ways to reduce the error when fitting an approximately fifth-order original signal?
Currently, my training and test set errors are both below 0.001, but the prediction error in the middle segment fluctuates significantly. Since the original signal lacks periodicity and only has a trend, which is quite different from conventional forecasting tasks, are there any methods to reduce this type of error?

How is the plot related to your question?
